# How to get the matched sub-groups in C# using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
{Lower Left  (  460700.000, 2121200.000)}
```

and here is my code:

```
    var pat = @"Lower Left\s*\(\s*[\d\.]+\,(\s)*[\d\.]+\)";
    var r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    var m = r.Match(s);
```

The m.Groups[0] now equals:

```
{Lower Left  (  460700.000, 2121200.000)}
```

But I want to get the coordinate strings in two variables, e.g. X and Y.  how to do it?

Comment: Like [`Lower Left\s*\(\s*(?<X>[\d\.]+),\s*(?<Y>[\d\.]+)\)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Lower+Left%5cs*%5c(%5cs*(%3f%3cX%3e%5b%5cd%5c.%5d%2b)%2c%5cs*(%3f%3cY%3e%5b%5cd%5c.%5d%2b)%5c)&i=%7bLower+Left++(++460700.000%2c+2121200.000)%7d)? See [**this demo**](http://ideone.com/vPWxwF).

Comment: You know you've not *wrapped* your `[\d\.]+` matches in capture groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
string s = "{Lower Left  (  460700.000, 2121200.000)}";

var pat = @"Lower Left\s*\(\s*(\d+\.\d+)\,\s*(\d+\.\d+)\)";
var r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var m = r.Match(s);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]); // first number
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2]); // second number
```

If your number may or may not contain `.`, you can use:

```
string s = "{Lower Left  (  460700.000, 2121200.000)}";

var pat = @"Lower Left\s*\(\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\,\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)";
var r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var m = r.Match(s);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2]);
```

This will accept this number: `123456` (no dot), `123.456` (one dot inside), but not `123.456.7` (two dot) or `1234.` (dot at the end).

Answer (score 1):

The first group allways returns the entire match, whilst the indexed ones contain your actual values for the matching groups. So you need `m.Groups[1]` and `m.Groups[1]` accordingly.

You can also name your groups:

```
@"Lower Left\s*\(\s*(?<X>\d+\.\d+),(\s)*(?<Y>\d+\.\d+)\)";
```

Where `(?<identifier>anyPattern)` means build a matching-group which is named `identifier` and has the pattern given by `anyPattern`. 
Allowing you to access them like this:

```
m.Groups["X"]
m.Groups["Y"]
```

The square-brackets (`[]`) are also not needed at all as this would mean "either a number od digits (`\d+`), or a dot", not "a number of digits followed by a dot followed by a number of digits".

Comment: m.Groups[n] for n >= 1  are ""  (with Success = False)